# Confused on aligning the content with Image

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a HTML code where there are a `span`s with some text and and Image beside them.

I'm trying to do the below.

1. Vertically center the content.
2. Make the div width as the width of content. i.e. the word should be in single line rather than break.
3. Make the content start from left (later I'll get rid of the borders and it will appear to be in a grid of 4 columns).

Working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vqvjtsLz/2/

```css
.resultTable {
  margin-top: 0.85em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 7.5px 0 rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.3);
}

.combiNum {
  height: 25%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1779d0;
}

.combiDiv {
  display: flex;
  height: 25%;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

span.mainspan0,
span.mainspan1,
span.mainspan2,
span.mainspan3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 0.85em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logoImageSpan {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -2%;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
}

span.elementClass {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultTable" id="resultTable">
  <div class="combiNum">Combination #1</div>
  <div class="combiDiv">
    <span class="mainspan0">
                    <span class="logoImageSpan">
                        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jphBQR/sulphide.png" alt="sulphide" border="0" />
                    </span>
    <span id="element1" class="elementClass">Sulphates</span>
    <span id="element2" class="elementClass">0.575</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mainspan1">
                    <span class="logoImageSpan">
                        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jRjQkR/alcohol.png" alt="alcohol" border="0" />
                    </span>
    <span id="element1" class="elementClass">Alcohol</span>
    <span id="element2" class="elementClass">10.25</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mainspan2">
                    <span class="logoImageSpan">
                        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cPWGs6/sulphurdioxide.png" alt="sulphurdioxide" border="0" />
                    </span>
    <span id="element1" class="elementClass">Total sulfur dioxide</span>
    <span id="element2" class="elementClass">98.5</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mainspan3">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/bT70Km/next.png" alt="next" border="0" />
                </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this close? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/7gbmfn9x/2/

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://jsfiddle.net/ow3x9mj3/

Comment: @Highdef content is getting overlapped, but love your idea of placing content below image, but I need the content in 1 line and the span width should be equal to this...

Comment: @user3872094 Because you're making use of flexbox, if it isn't an issue for the columns to wrap down in other row this will get fixed. But after a certain minimum width if you try to shrink further, ofcourse the content will overlap. Try to resize the width.

Comment: @sol bro `Total Sulfur Dioxide` is cut :-(

Comment: @Highdef I really love any other suggestions, apologies, ain't an UI guy :-(

Comment: Well, here's another suggestion. How does this look ?https://jsfiddle.net/pbcdzew8/ The font is made responsive by making it relative to the viewport width using 2vw. Now, the content won't overlap as the font gets resized as well.

Comment: @Highdef this guy is beautiful. Thanks alot bro...

Comment: @Highdef yes, plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mainspan0..3 has obtained the following changes** :

```
display: flex;
   align-items: center; /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: center; /*Aligns contents horizontally */
  text-align: center; /*Aligns further text in the center */
  flex-direction:column; /*By default its row, you can change to column for vertical alignment */
  font-size:2vw;
```

**And elementClass has been modified so the text doesnt break:**

```
span.elementClass {
  flex:1;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```css
.resultTable {
  margin-top: 0.85em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 7.5px 0 rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.3);
}

.combiNum {
  height: 25%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1779d0;
}

.combiDiv {
  display: flex;
  height: 25%;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

span.mainspan0,
span.mainspan1,
span.mainspan2,
span.mainspan3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 0.85em;
  display: flex;
   align-items: center; /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: center; /*Aligns contents horizontally */
  text-align: center; /*Aligns further text in the center */
  flex-direction:column; /*By default its row, you can change to column for vertical alignment */
  font-size:2vw;

}

.logoImageSpan {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -2%;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
}

span.elementClass {
  flex:1;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultTable" id="resultTable">
  <div class="combiNum">Combination #1</div>
  <div class="combiDiv">
    <span class="mainspan0">
                <span class="logoImageSpan">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jphBQR/sulphide.png" alt="sulphide" border="0" />
                </span>
    <span id="element1" class="elementClass">Sulphates</span>
    <span id="element2" class="elementClass">0.575</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mainspan1">
                <span class="logoImageSpan">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jRjQkR/alcohol.png" alt="alcohol" border="0" />
                </span>
    <span id="element1" class="elementClass">Alcohol</span>
    <span id="element2" class="elementClass">10.25</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mainspan2">
                <span class="logoImageSpan">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cPWGs6/sulphurdioxide.png" alt="sulphurdioxide" border="0" />
                </span>
    <span id="element1" class="elementClass">Total sulfur dioxide</span>
    <span id="element2" class="elementClass">98.5</span>
    </span>
    <span class="mainspan3">
                <img src="https://image.ibb.co/bT70Km/next.png" alt="next" border="0" />
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```